# Looking for a non-fiction book on RPG gaming from the late '80s

Tags: product-identification, books

I've read a few similar questions on RPG.SE - I know for sure that the book I'm looking for is neither [Dicing with Dragons](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0451144899) nor [Fantasy Wargaming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0812828623).

I was nearly sure it was Dicing with Dragons. However, I bought that book and I can tell it's not the same one. It doesn't break down D&D for the layman like I remember this one doing.

Here are some miscellaneous things I remember about the book:

- I remember the book from when I was a teen, in the late 80s.
- It was published before 1990.
- It talked about getting into RPGs, not specifically Fantasy.
- It talked about multiple RPGs (I think so).
- It must have been talking about D&D, but it wasn't specific to D&D, since I remember it used Comic Book characters as references.
- I feel like it was trade paperback-like.

I don't remember much more than what is listed above.

The part that I recall most vividly every time I think about the book, is that **somewhere in the book it mentions D&D style ability scores and it describes Strength compared to Superman and Constitution related to the Hulk, or something similar**.

I would love to find this again. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

It could have been [John Eric Holmes' "Fantasy Role Playing Games"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/783473.Fantasy_Role_Playing_Games) from 1981.

He gives an overview of several systems including "Tunnels & Trolls" and "Chivalry & Sorcery". I recall a nice piece of advice for first time players: don't get too attached to your first character; send in a "scout" with the expectation of a possible quick character death, and save that wonderful little elf or hobbit for later :-)

Comment: As it seems to be the question's centerpiece, is there any mention of superheroes in *Fantasy Role Playing Games*?

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have a copy to confirm this particular passage, but it matches in all the other particulars.